# How to delete emails from specific sender by python

Tags: python, email

I'd like to delete email from specific sender with python.

Here is my codes to delete all emails from my email account.

**Question 1)** How can I delete specific emails from specific sender? (ex: anyspamsender@gmail.com)

**Question 2)** How can I delete specific emails of which email title contains specific text ? (title : Delivery Status Notification (Failure))

```
import imaplib
box = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
box.login("emailid","password")
box.select('Inbox')
typ, data = box.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
   box.store(num, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
box.expunge()
box.close()
box.logout()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
typ, data = box.search(None, 'from','mailer-daemon@googlemail.com')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This does nothing to actually delete those messages.